# MariaDB / MySQL: Index hint ignored when there is left join

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, mariadb

Consider there are 2M records in both shipment and order table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s0_.id         AS id0,
    s0_.updated_at AS updated_at1
FROM
    `shipment` s0_
        LEFT JOIN `order` s1_ ON s0_.order_id = s1_.id -- These line
        LEFT JOIN `address` s2_ ON s1_.shipping_address_id = s2_.id -- These line
ORDER BY s0_.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

If I remove the left join MariaDB will use the index specified, why? Is there any solution?

**This SQL is generated by a library and I have limited options to fix it.**

**This SQL is generated by a library and I have limited options to fix it.**

**This SQL is generated by a library and I have limited options to fix it.**

**This SQL is generated by a library and I have limited options to fix it.**

**This SQL is generated by a library and I have limited options to fix it.**

Don't ask me to remove it. I know it has no use. And I think query optimizer need to think so too as it is just **LEFT** JOIN.

I am using MariaDB 10.1

Comment: `EXPLAIN {query}` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE shipment` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders` to see what indexes you have.

Comment: [order by limit clauses](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=labels%20%3D%20order-by-optimization%20and%20status!%3Dclosed) have a few optimizations to go.

Comment: Report the `LEFT JOIN`s as a bug in the Pagerfanta library :-) Take responsibility for the code you use.

Comment: You could fork the project and fix it. https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta

Comment: I seriously want to delete this question

Answer (score 1):

The left join needs to find the `order_id` of the shipment before it orders the output.

Forcing the index is usually the wrong thing to do, even if it can discover some things.

Use a compound index of `shipment(order_id, updated_at)` and you won't need to force an index.

ref: [compound indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1)
[query optimization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization)

Comment: I think you are correct, but it is also silly to see the optimizer process this query like this as it is just LEFT JOIN

Comment: Can you check the updated question? Your solution works if there is only one direct left join but not like the updated query

Comment: When I remove DISTINCT, then it is fast. s0_.id is primary key already. Do I need to add a unique constraint? Will it works?

Comment: a primary key is always unique, so yes, distinct isn't needed. `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` info please. The additional join on `addresses` isn't used in the result set or any aspect of filtering.

Comment: This whole query is generated by Pagerfanta